# Localization of a ring at one element

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra

Let $A$ be a commutative ring with identity, $f$ an element of $A$, let $g'=g/1$ be the image of the element $g$ of $A$ in $A_f$ under the natural homomorphism $A\rightarrow A_f$. The question is:

> Is $A_{fg}$  isomorphic to $(A_f)_{g'}$?

Any comment will be appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A more general result holds:

> Let $S,T$ be multiplicative sets in a commutative ring $A$, $i_S:A\to A_S$ the canonical homomorphism, and $T'=i_S(T)$. Then there is a unique isomorphism $j:A_{ST}\to (A_S)_{T'}$ such that $j\circ i_{ST}=i_{T'}\circ i_S$, that is, $j$ makes the following diagram to commute
>   \begin{array}
> & & A\ \ \ \ \ \stackrel{i_S}\longrightarrow  & A_S \\ 
> & \downarrow i_{ST} &\downarrow i_{T'} \\
> & A_{ST}\ \stackrel{j}\longrightarrow & (A_S)_{T'} \\ 
> \end{array}

For proving this use the universality property of rings of fractions.

Comment: @benh You are right: if $S=\{1,f,f^2,\dots\}$ and $T=\{1,g,g^2,\dots\}$, then $ST\ne \{1,fg,(fg)^2,\dots\}$, but even so we have $A_{ST}=A_{fg}$ and this matters.

Comment: +1 Clear explanation in terms of the universal property. @benh You're discovering that different multiplicative sets can lead to the same localizations, yes?

Comment: @user26857 Yes, you are absolutely right, I am sorry.

Comment: Surely you only get that $j$ is an isomorphism if you assume that your ring is an integral domain, right?

Comment: @subobject_classifier No, is not right!

Comment: Right, I was just trying to show an isomorphism directly and ended up appealing to lack of zero divisors. It seems the best way is to use the universal mapping property. Thanks!